# Use currency symbol with HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, utf-8

I am writing a basic HTML5 with some JavaScript.

I am using the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And I have set my UTF-8 encoding like do (in the head tag):

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

The problem is, I have this javascript object which looks is exactly like this:

```
var symbol = {"GBP":"£", "EUR":"€", "USD":"$"};
alert(symbol['GBP']);
```

When the object is called it returns with the infamous �!

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: It works here.. Have you tested it among different browsers?

Comment: Yes, Firefox, Chrome and IE. Which all use different renderers

Comment: Have you checked what encoding is actually detected by browser?

Comment: Are your files saved with UTF-8 encoding? Are all files being served to the browser with UFT-8 encoding? Suggestion: Set the encoding in the HTTP headers rather than meta tags.

Comment: The file containing the javascript is not saved as UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, when you use the alert function, it doesn't like using special characters.  My code was absolutely fine when I used the special characters in the HTML document. So instead I used something like this:

```
$(this).html(symbol['GPB']);
```

Thanks for your effort guys!

Peter

Answer (score 3):

Some steps you don't mention:

- Configure your editor to save files as UTF-8
- Configure your web server to send `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 2):

What editor do you use? There is a possibility that you editor saves file in some iso8859 encoding. Try to use for example notepad and save file in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use HTML Entity instead.

```
var symbol = {"GBP":"&#163;", "EUR":"&#8364;", "USD":"&#36;"};
```